# 802.1x. Different options from WIFI to Wired

Tags: networking, wireless, authentication, wired

this is the problem I have seen between these connections and their configuration options:
When we configure 802.1x with EAP protected (PEAP) in a wired interface we have this:
[802.1x Wired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNQsp.png)

But when we connect via wireless interface with 802.1x authentication we get this options:

[802.1x wireless](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlbE6.png)

The question is, why is not able the "No CA certificate is required" checkbox in the wired 802.1x options?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What Operating System is this?

I this a macOS? Elementary OS? Can you give us more info?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved.

OS was Ubuntu and there was a incorrect implementation of config options.

Now works fine.